# How did Ron enter into the Chamber of Secrets?

Tags: harry-potter

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* Ron enters into the the 'Chamber of Secrets' by mimicking parseltongue. How exactly could he enter into Chamber when he is not the one. Does the magic on doors not recognize whether the person is really s parseltongue or not?

> What is certain is that by the time Slytherin was forced out of the school by the other three founders, he had decided that henceforth, the Chamber he had built would be the lair of a monster that he alone – or his descendants – would be able to control: a Basilisk. Moreover, only a Parselmouth would be able to enter the Chamber

Comment: Related, and the answers there _could_ make it a duplicate: [How did Ron speak Parseltongue and re-enter the Chamber of Secrets?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/81081/98028). Also note that Ginny could enter though she wasn't a Parselmouth nor a Heir of Slytherin

Comment: You can speak phrases in a language without being able to speak the language

Comment: Fixed mindset vs growth mindset? Can one learn to be a Parselmouth given not just anyone can learn to be a wizard/witch in the HP universe? @JoeW

Comment: @bclc we only meat a handful of people who know how to speak it and they all knew it naturally. I saw no evidence either way that someone with the right talents couldn't learn it. And considering how people viewed speaking it I don't think many people tried to learn it.

Comment: Though I really dislike that question, the top answer immediately answers how Ron got in.

Comment: @JoeW Oh wrong question. Revise: Can one learn to speak phrases of Parseltongue given not just anyone can learn to be a wizard/witch in the HP universe, which I think generalises to that not just anyone can learn to cast a spell (casting a spell is to being a witch/wizard as speaking phrases is to speaking a language) in the HP universe?

Comment: Also is the magic on door is so weak that it couldn't identify that Ron is not a parseltongue? it's quite hard to believe. Also I believe parseltongue is not a language but is a person with that quality. Am I right?